# django- how to check validity of single input field inside multi input form

Tags: django

I have a form with multiple input fields, but only want to use one input from the form.  What is the proper way to check field validity and get cleaned data for the one field?

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way would probably be to add it to it's own form ;)

But... you can do it like this:

```
form = SomeForm(request.POST)
field = form.fields['your_field']
data = field.widget.value_from_datadict(form.data, form.files, form.add_prefix('your_field'))
cleaned_data = field.clean(data)
```

Comment: This was perfect, thanks. I was trying to pre-populate a registration form if they were on the login page and had entered a username and then clicked "register" instead of "login".

Comment: That should be `field = form.fields['your_field']` notice the `s` in `form.fields`